# весь рабочий стол изменился из за Git помогите

Tags: git

я начинающий недавно хотел установить  bower в git не получилось кроме того весь рабочий стол стал таким с плюсиками большими и уродливыми  я написал только там добавить git add Desktop/ и все стало так проста там было написано untracked files и несколько файлов и каталогов я хотел посмотреть что будет когда добавлю  помогите пожалуйста как убрать это все чтобы стало как прежде[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй найти на рабочем столе скрытую папку **.git** и удалить ее

Comment: Красиво же, зачем убирать, всё под контролем.

Comment: @ Leonid спасибо большое

Comment: Нам интересна не высококонтрастная картинка в качество обоев рабочего стола, а **содержимое папки `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop`**.

Comment: @Arhad а что, между `%HOMEDRIVE%` и `%HOMEPATH%` слеш не нужен? (я совсем в винде плохо разбираюсь)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, не нужен: https://i.stack.imgur.com/53XNI.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

удалить скрытую папку **.git** на рабочем столе